# Is length contraction actually get things smaller or is it just how one reference frame look at things?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, observers

I want to check something..
when we nearly reach the speed of light, we'd look the length of things differently. Although we know that the speed of light is the same for all reference  frames. Is it because when we at that speed somehow the lenght of things are actually minimized or is it just how we look at it, but not actually getting smaller?

The similar other example which I'm still confused at. It's about the lorentz transformation x'= y(x-vt).
Based on that equation. Let's say we have 3 objects (A, B, C) and let's say the velocity of A is 0.1c, velocity of B is 0.8c and velocity of C is 0.9c. And imagine if we stop all the time, so there won't be any transformation of energies. Then let's say we are at A and we see the distance of B to C is 1 million years of c. Though while the time still freezing if we change the reference frame to B, based on that equation x'= y(x-vt) we need to multiply the result by y. So the distance of B to C won't be 1 million years of c. But y*(1 millions years of c), whether 0.8 million.. or etc. I want to check does it work that way? or I misinterpreted something?

Comment: Length contraction is real.  Do a Google search for cosmic ray muons that are detected at ground level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Reality" of length contraction in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148216/)

Comment: If you're asking if things in relative motion are contracted due to motion and remain contracted when there is no more motion, the answer is no. See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506977/in-the-twin-paradox-does-the-returning-twin-also-come-back-permanently-length-co).